# Отметки на счётчике input [type="range"]

Tags: input

Доброго дня!
Столкнулся с проблемой - нужно реализовать счётчик с ползунком, при этом на полосе должны быть отметки (типа линейки). Вот никак не пойму - как эти отметки реализовать. http://prntscr.com/gsd65w

Comment: `background-image`

Comment: @Igor а на css, слабо? :D

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy , можешь набросать как? Сам ничего не смог найти(

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy а `background-image: linear-gradient()` - это уже не css?

Comment: @Cheg ммм. у тебя засечек нет. я думал были))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думаю, главное - способ реализации. А засечки додумать - не проблема)

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov попробуй разобрать на части и удалить лишнее отсюда https://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/rOVrGK   ..... может быть понадобится

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("label").eq(0).css("backgroundSize", $("label").eq(0).width() / (20 / 5)+"px");
```

```css
label{
background-image:linear-gradient(to left, transparent 98%, gray 0%);
background-size:10px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="range" step="5" max="20"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    label
                    span
                        |Продано полисов КАСКО на сумму
                    input(type="range" class="range" min="0" max="1000000" step="1" value="400000")
                    .value--wfa
                        .value__item--wfa
                        .value__item--wfa
                        .value__item--wfa
                        .value__item--wfa
                        .value__item--wfa   


.value--wfa
    display: flex
    width: 100%
    position: absolute
    max-width: 738px
    width: 100%
    left: 342.5px
    z-index: 0

.value__item--wfa
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1
    height: 21px
    width: 20%

.value__item--wfa:first-child
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1
```